How to use toSpliced() without copying the type?
I want to try out the toSpliced() method:
const a = [1, 2] as const 
const b = a.toSpliced(0, 1, 'hi') 

This gives error: Argument of type '"hi"' is not assignable to parameter of type '1 | 2'
I try copy the array:
const copiedA = [...a] //or
const copiedA = a.map(x => x)

or type assert it:
const b = a.toSpliced(0, 1, 'hi') as any

but none of these works. Is there a way to avoid this?

(a as (number | string)[]).toSpliced(…)?

Have to use (a as unknown as (number | string)[]).toSpliced to make it error-free

What is the error otherwise?

Conversion of type 'readonly [1, 2]' to type '(string | number)[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. 

The type of a is readonly [1, 2].
If you want to treat it as something else, you can cast it using as.
const b = (a as readonly any[]).toSpliced(0, 1, 'hi')

or in two lines
const anyArr: readonly any[] = a
const c = anyArr.toSpliced(0, 1, 'hi')

You should replace any with whatever is suitable.
